# .appendTo within a for loop only works on half the elements

Tags: jquery, function, for-loop, slideshow

I am dynamically generating an element which I put the images into in a slideshow so that it doesn't loop any arrows that I generate or pagers and I have used a for loop to put it in but not the element to itself though what happens is that elements one and three are put in though none of the others are.

Here is the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < looper; i++) {
    $(this).children().eq(i).appendTo($(this).find('.holderjkdfgjkdfg'));
}
```

Here is the code in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/2cb2L/

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem and what are you trying to do with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < looper; i++) {
    $(this).children().eq(0).appendTo($(this).find('.holderjkdfgjkdfg'));
}
```

where eq(i) should be changed to eq(0) so that each time the loop ran, the top most 'img' tag was picked off.

In your code, the first time the loop ran 'i' was 0 and this pointed to the first element which was then removed from the original div and moved to the '.holderjkdfgjkdfg' div. The second time the loop ran, there were only 3 elements in the original div but 'i' had incremented to 1. eq(1) would be the second element of the remaining 3 elements (which is in effect the third of the original 4 elements). Hope you understood that :).

Comment: thanks for your help though found another way of doing it without a for loop